# How to change the key binding of "Go to File" of textmate?

Tags: textmate, key-bindings

I want to change the key binding of "Go to File" of textmate from it's default one <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts.

Click *App Shortcuts* and then the plus button to create a new entry.

Select TextMate as application, set menu title to ***Go to File…*** (including the ellipsis) and then pick your desired key equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Head into System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts.

Add a new Application (Textmate) and the Menu Title should be 'Go to File..."

I tried just using 'Go to File' but found out the actual title requires the additional '...'

Comment: Good point about the ellipsis. Note this is also the case for  `"Find and Replace..."`, `"Find in Project...",` `"Find in Folder..."` and many more.